# Flutter: failing when calling from iOS

Tags: flutter

This is working on Android:

```
call(BuildContext context, String phoneNumber) async {
    String url = "tel://" + phoneNumber;
    if (await canLaunch(url)) { // with this the simulator loses connection and on real device it just doesn't work (url_launcher)
    await launch(url); // without the above, this line does nothing (also no error)
    } else {
      _showError(context);
    }
  }
```

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!

Comment: Are you running this on Simulator? Run it on a physical device.

Comment: on simulator it stops and on real device it doesn't do anything

Comment: it should be ``tel://`` instead of ``tel//:`` !!

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. Same error anyway (fixed)